# QueueUserWorkItem switch back to background thread after a BeginInvoke?

Tags: c#, wpf, threadpool, dispatcher

This is a code sample. Imagine it is not a `ViewModel` and nothing related to it.

**Explanation:**

So I have a `ObservableCollection` with items I want do delete from database. 
To avoid block UI I call it in a background thread.

If I have a database problem or it succeeds I want to show in the UI. So I call a little code in `Dispacther.BeginInvoke`.

I know that calling `BeginInvoke` will change the thread context to UI.

**Code sample:**

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((o) =>
{
    Action completedAction = null;
    try
    {
        //Delete from database;
        item.Delete();
        completedAction = () => { this.Observable.Remove(item); };
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        completedAction = () =>
        {
            someTextBox.Text = "Error";
        };
    }

    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(completedAction);
}));
```

**Question:**

I want to know if even thought I did not write more code after `BeginInvoke` it will change thread context back to the background thread.

PS. I know I can use `BackgroundWorker` but to me looks simpler to use `QueueUserWorkItem` to do that.

Comment: BeginInvoke executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the Dispatcher's thread. It will not "change the thread context" of the calling object. You can safely execute more "background" code after calling BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BeginInvoke method "queues" the work to be done on the UI thread (it may be already busy doing something else).  After BeginInvoke, the background thread continues to run the rest of your delegate.  When its done running your delegate that background thread ( a thread pool thread ) is returned to the pool to be potentially reused.  So, yes, the code after BeginInvoke is run on the background thread.

Comment: Your answer looks pretty good. So BeginInvoke send the method to the UI queue. No context change happen calling it. Very good. If nobody asnwer better I will mark your as the accepcted.

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works.  Only the delegate that you are passing to BeginInvoke will be executed on the UI thread- any code after `BeginInvoke` will occur on the background thread.

Comment: Yes. It I understood. I really want to know if happen context changes between BeginInvoke. But I think @Peter-Ritchie clarify that for me.